# How do I write a JavaScript function to filter a URLs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, tracking

I am trying to write a function in JavaScript (or any clientside technology that is capable of it) to allow a URL to be tested against a list of URLs that are to be tracked (using Bing Conversion Tracking). I have the bases of what is required but I am unsure of how its meant to be applied.

```
var isCorrectPage = false;
//loop through list of URLS

isCorrectPage = true;

if (isCorrectPage) {
// enter the bespoke tracking code
}
```

I am unsure of exactly the way it checks the validity of the URL, should I then loop through a list of the selected URLs for tracking?

@ Ivan Nevostruev 
I want to filter some URLs that will be similar but have different page numbers, The URLs are like:

```
"/find-enquiry-thanks.aspx?did=62" 
"/find-enquiry thanks.aspx?did=90"
"/find-enquiry thanks.aspx?did=38"
"/future-contact thanks.aspx"
```

If the URL = true then I will attach tracking to that URL.
In VB.net the contains() or a binary search could be used but with JS I am stuck.

Comment: Can you provide more examples of urls and expected results?

Comment: Please see the URLs that I have just added in the above code snippet. Thank you

Comment: Are you asking of how to use `str.indexOf("...")`  or `str.match(regexp)` in JS ? Where you "stack" at ?

Comment: I need it to loop over the items in paths and compare them to a lowercase version of the location.href. Then I will have to call a trackingcode method()

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean based on the current URL? You want something like this maybe:

```
function check(url, paths) {
  return !!paths.find(function (path) {
    return url.indexOf(path) !== -1;
  });
}

var paths = [
  "/find-enquiry-thanks.aspx?did=62",
  "/find-enquiry thanks.aspx?did=90",
  "/find-enquiry thanks.aspx?did=38",
  "/future-contact thanks.aspx",
];

if (check(window.location.href, paths)) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Note, `Array.prototype.find` is new and not all browsers have it so if you want what it does you might want to look at lodash/underscore `_.find` or just make a messy for loop that returns:

```
  function check(url, paths) {
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
      if (url.indexOf(path) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I am going to be able to use the Array.prototype.find as it is not widely enough supported. I am guessing that I will need to implement a loop over the items in paths and compare them to a lowercase version of the location.href - if they match then add call trackingcode method(). I am not sure how to write this out. I think it is similar to the loop you have written above??

Comment: I can't be sure since I don't know what your existing code looks like, but lodash or underscore ships with a _.find method that works the same as Array.prototype.find. You might want to consider that.

Comment: I have tried a _.find method and this doesn't seem to work on it either. How would I implement a loop? It would just need to loop over the items in paths and compare them to a lowercase version of the location.href.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(function(){
    var pageUrl = window.location.href;
    var urls = ["/find-enquiry-thanks.aspx?did=62","/find-enquiry-thanks.aspx?did=90","/find-enquiry-thanks.aspx?did=38","/future-contact-thanks.aspx"];

    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
        if (pageUrl.indexOf(urls[i]) > 0){
            document.write('valid url');
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Will this loop allow mer loop over the items in paths and compare them to a lowercase version of the location.href? Then I will call a trackingcode method()

Comment: Yes. Call your method instead of `document.write('valid url');`. Also you can use `toLowerCase()` string method to be sure that the url is lower case.

Comment: I see, so it would be:               getBing('valid url');      at which part of the function will I call the toLowerCase() string method? after its checked to see if its a valid URL or before?

Comment: You can call `toLowerCase()` on both links when checking the condition: `if (pageUrl.toLowerCase().indexOf(urls[i].toLowerCase()) > 0){`